# Sqlite add tablename before column defintions

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

When it is allowed to write the tablename before a columnname to make a query more accurate.

For example. I have a table "customer" with a column "name". It is ok to write in each sql statement "customer.name" instead of "name"?
Can i use the long version also in create statements?
I know that the long version prevent errors in join statements so why not using it all the time.

Comment: `why not using it all the time` because it's **not needed**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INSERT/UDPATE/DELETE statements can operate only on a single table, so you must specify plain column names, and cannot rename the table with an alias. (Well, DELETE does not specify columns.)

However, this is different when using subqueries; with SELECT, all features are available:

```
UPDATE MyTable                 -- no alias allowed
SET ParentName =               -- no table name allowed
        (SELECT T2.Name
         FROM MyTable AS T2
         WHERE T2.ID = MyTable.ParentID);
```